# Constructing a function pointer to alloca causes linker errors?

Tags: c, function-pointers, alloca

I am trying to write a function that is passed a function to use for allocation as its argument; it should accept any valid allocator of type `void *(*)(size_t)`.  However I am experiencing strange behavior when attempting to use `alloca` as the allocator - constructing a function pointer to the `alloca` function compiles fine but results in linker errors:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alloca.h>

int main() {
  void *(*foo)(size_t) = alloca;
}
```

results in

```
/tmp/cc8F67yC.o: In function `main':
test15.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `alloca'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does this have something to do with alloca being inlined?  But wouldn't inlining only be done as an optimization when the function doesn't need to have an address.  In fact, with GCC I can even write my own version that does work as expected in the above code:

```
static inline void *alloca(size_t n) {
  return __builtin_alloca(n);
}
```

Is there a reason why the standard version doesn't behave the same way?

Comment: Probably because the compiler replaces all calls of `alloca` directly with `__builtin_alloca`?

Comment: `alloca` isn't really a function. It's a compiler builtin, which is given a function-like syntax by people of infinite wisdom and sagacity. Your own version works as expected in the above code, but alas it doesn't work as `alloca` at all. The function itself might work in `gcc` if you give it an `__attribute__((always_inline))`, but the address of the function won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the man pages from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html):

> The fact that the code is inlined means that it is impossible to take
>   the address of this function, or to change its behavior by linking
>   with a different library.

The page also mentions:

> messy consequences if one has a private version of this function

Answer (score 8):

Who says your function

```
static inline void *alloca(size_t n) {
    return __builtin_alloca(n);
}
```

works? The object allocated by `__builtin_alloca` meets its lifetime at the end of the function so as soon as you return it, you've got a dangling pointer already!

Comment: I overlooked that, somehow.  Testing the function worked fine, but that was probably just because I had a pointer to an address in my `alloca`'s stack frame, and didn't call any functions that would overwrite this address.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you propose. `alloca` is a very special beast, it can only be called explicitly inside a function body and not within the argument expressions of a function call.

Note that there is no *standard version* of `alloca`. Neither the C Standard nor POSIX describe this function.

The alternative you expose, with `alloca` redefined as an inline function calling `__builtin_alloca` does not work: among other problems, the pointer returned by `__builtin_alloca()` is only valid until the caller returns, whether it is inlined or not.

The [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) is very explicit:

> [...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `alloca()` function allocates size bytes of space in the stack
>          frame of the caller.  This temporary space is automatically freed
>          when the function that called `alloca()` returns to its caller.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `alloca()` function returns a pointer to the beginning of the
>          allocated space.  If the allocation causes stack overflow, program
>          behavior is undefined.
>
> [...]
>
> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> This function is not in POSIX.1.
>
> There is evidence that the `alloca()` function appeared in 32V, PWB,
>          PWB.2, 3BSD, and 4BSD.  There is a man page for it in 4.3BSD.  Linux
>          uses the GNU version.
>
> **NOTES**
>
> The `alloca()` function is machine- and compiler-dependent.  For
>          certain applications, its use can improve efficiency compared to the
>          use of `malloc(3)` plus `free(3)`.  In certain cases, it can also
>          simplify memory deallocation in applications that use `longjmp(3)` or
>          `siglongjmp(3)`.  Otherwise, its use is discouraged.
>
> Because the space allocated by `alloca()` is allocated within the stack
>          frame, that space is automatically freed if the function return is
>          jumped over by a call to `longjmp(3)` or `siglongjmp(3)`.
>
> The space allocated by `alloca()` is not automatically deallocated if
>          the pointer that refers to it simply goes out of scope.
>
> Do not attempt to `free(3)` space allocated by `alloca()`!
>
> **Notes on the GNU version**
>
> Normally, gcc(1) translates calls to `alloca()` with inlined code.
>          This is not done when either the `-ansi`, `-std=c89`, `-std=c99`, or the
>          `-std=c11` option is given and the header `<alloca.h>` is not included.
>          Otherwise, (without an `-ansi` or `-std=c*` option) the glibc version of
>          `<stdlib.h>` includes `<alloca.h>` and that contains the lines:
>
> ```
>       #ifdef  __GNUC__
>        #define alloca(size)   __builtin_alloca (size)
>        #endif
> ```
>
> with messy consequences if one has a private version of this function.
>
> The fact that the code is inlined means that it is impossible to take
>         the address of this function, or to change its behavior by linking
>          with a different library.
>
> The inlined code often consists of a single instruction adjusting the
>          stack pointer, and does not check for stack overflow.  Thus, there is
>          no `NULL` error return.
>
> **BUGS**
>
> There is no error indication if the stack frame cannot be extended.
>          (However, after a failed allocation, the program is likely to receive
>          a `SIGSEGV` signal if it attempts to access the unallocated space.)
>
> On many systems `alloca()` cannot be used inside the list of arguments
>          of a function call, because the stack space reserved by `alloca()`
>          would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function
>          arguments.